# Is Realterm dropping characters or am I?

Tags: terminal, serial-port, atmel, terminal-emulator, usart

I'm using a SAML21 board to accept some data over a serial connection, and at the moment, just mirror it to a serial port on a computer. However this data is 6 bytes at ~250Hz(It was closer to 3KHz before). As far as I can tell I'm tracking the start and end bytes correctly, however my columnar alignment gets out of whack on occasion in realterm.

I have it set up for 6 bytes in single mode. SO all columns should be presenting the same bytes up and down. However, over time as I increase the rate at which I mirror(I am still receiving the data at a fixed rate) the first column's byte tends to float.

I have not used realterm at speeds this high before, so I am not aware of it's limitations.

Comment: "columnar alignment" is completely meaningless when talking about serial ports.  They don't have columns.  Getting a variable number of bytes for each read call, increasing at higher baudrates, that's entirely normal.  It is a stream of bytes, you always need a good protocol to know when you got the "last" one.

Comment: OP says he is tracking start/end bytes. Not obvious to me that "Getting a variable number...increasing at higher baudrates, that's entirely normal" is true at all. If the communication is reliable and OP expects to get six chars on every line, why should the baudrate affect what is received?

Comment: What baud rate are you using for input and output? On the SAML21, can you check that there are six bytes between start/end and perhaps count the times there aren't six? Same when transmitting - code to count the number of times there aren't six bytes in what is sent? Presumably on the SAML 21 board you are putting the received data in a buffer, and then re-transmitting it from that buffer? Can you check that the buffer isn't overflowing perhaps by keeping a running maximum of the buffer length?

Comment: @HansPassant I'm speaking of allignment in terms of the terminal im using to view the data. It should be formatted in regular columns, and it is. However, what is 'First' shifts. In my experience, that's not normal. So that's why I'm trying to determine the source of the fault.

Comment: @barny 115200. I have a buffer that receives a maximum of 6 bytes and transmits them when done receiving. I am evaluating this at the top of each transmission cycle to ensure that data on my end in in the correct order. "if (rx_buffer[0] != 0b11111110 || rx_buffer[1] != 0b11111110 || (rx_buffer[5] &0x1F != 0))" Due to the nature of the data, I had to use two start bytes to ensure accuracy. The lower 5 bits of the last byte must be 0. This statement at present just increments a counter which I can check during debug.

Comment: When you say "done receiving", does the source pause until it receives a character, or wait for a specific time? IME it would be more normal to add received data to e.g. a 256-byte ring buffer, and pull it off the buffer as needed, allows some variation in speed of reception/consumption. With flow control when e.g. 192 characters in buffer try to stop the sender, and when the level drops to e.g. 128 bytes allow the sender to send again. Anyway in this scheme you can monitor the buffer length and spot overflow. What happens if sender starts sending before all six are re-transmitted?

Comment: or a 16-byte ring buffer - basically need enough space to handle bursts. At 115200 a char takes <100us, the CPU isn't doing anything which might block interrupts for >200us is it because that would mean it might occasionally miss a received character. Test the sending by writing some code which sends the same six characters (or a known pattern) and does nothing else, i.e. no received data, and check that the sent data looks good.

Comment: I have the same problem. I am sending bytes from Realterm to an FPGA over a USB tunnel. I have a ring buffer on the FPGA. Characters get lost randomly when I enter them manually in Relterm, but not when I send a binary file. This problem is independent of the BAUD rate.